# PureScript functions giving wrong type at runtime

Tags: jquery, functional-programming, purescript

Here's a function I wrote in PureScript. It compiles with no errors or warnings. The function does some setting up to handle mouse movement:

```
startMouseHandlers :: forall h e. STRef h {x::Number, y::Number}
  -> STRef h {x::Number, y::Number}
  -> Eff (dom :: DOM, st :: ST h | e) Unit
startMouseHandlers angleRef velocityRef = do
  lastMousePos <- newSTRef {x: 0.0, y: 0.0}
  body <- JQuery.body
  let
    moveHandler event jq = do
    x <- getPageX event
    y <- getPageY event
    lastPos <- readSTRef lastMousePos
    angle <- readSTRef angleRef
    let newAngle = {
          x: angle.x + x - lastPos.x,
          y: angle.y + y - lastPos.y
        }
    rotateCube angleRef newAngle
    void $ writeSTRef lastMousePos {x: x, y: y}
  on "mousemove" movehandler body
```

`angleRef` and `velocityRef` are `STRef` variables that reference mutable variables. They are being passed in by a calling function.

And here's the compiled JavaScript version of the same code snippet:

```
var startMouseHandlers = function (angleRef) {
      return function (velocityRef) {
      return function __do() {
          var v = Control_Monad_ST.newSTRef({
              x: 0.0, 
              y: 0.0
          })();
          var v1 = Control_Monad_Eff_JQuery.body();
          var moveHandler = function (event) {
              return function (jq) {
                  return function __do() {
                      var v2 = Control_Monad_Eff_JQuery.getPageX(event)();
                      var v3 = Control_Monad_Eff_JQuery.getPageY(event)();
                      var v4 = Control_Monad_ST.readSTRef(v)();
                      var v5 = Control_Monad_ST.readSTRef(angleRef)();
                      var newAngle = {
                          x: (v5.x + v2) - v4.x, 
                          y: (v5.y + v3) - v4.y
                      };
                      rotateCube(angleRef)(newAngle)();
                      return Data_Functor["void"](Control_Monad_Eff.functorEff)(Control_Monad_ST.writeSTRef(v)({
                          x: v2, 
                          y: v3
                      }))();
                  };
              };
          };
          return Control_Monad_Eff_JQuery.on("mousemove")(moveHandler)(v1)();
      };
      };
  };
```

This is the problem I'm facing: The point of this snippet is to call the `rotateCube` function with the newly calculated angle obtained from the mouse movement and stored in `newAngle`.

However, when I run this code in the browser, it doesn't do what I want it to do. I then tried debugging the JavaScript code and I discovered that the `newAngle` variable ends up having the value of

```
{ x: NaN, y: NaN }
```

After tracing the code I found out the reason was because the variable `v5.x` (which is `angle.x` in PureScript) has a value that is of `Number` type, *but* the variables `v2` and `v4.x` (`x` and `lastPos.x`) have the following type

```
v2: Object[1]
  0: 127
  length: 1
```

instead of being a `Number`. The same thing happens in the case of `y` and `lastPos.y`. I'm guessing the addition of this with the `Number` type of `angle.x` results in `NaN`. But why is that happening? Why aren't `x` and `lastPos.x` turning out to be `Number`s at runtime in javascript and instead look like these arrays?

I'm not sure if this is a clue or not, but the `on` function in `Control.Monad.Eff.JQuery` takes a function as an argument (in this case, `moveHandler`) that will be executed when the event occurs and that function should be of type

```
(JQueryEvent -> JQuery -> Eff (dom :: DOM | eff) a))
```

But inside `moveHandler` I have two side effects, one is `DOM` and the other is `ST` because of using `readSTRef`.

I actually tried explicitly declaring the type for `moveHandler` before it's definition like this

```
moveHandler :: forall e h. JQueryEvent -> JQuery -> Eff (dom :: DOM, st :: ST h | eff) Unit))
```

But this would always give me a `Could not match type` error, which is why I ended up just not mentioning an explicit type for `moveHandler`. Could this be a reason why the code isn't working? Is it not possible to have an `ST` effect also happening in the event handler callback function?

Comment: It's possible that the type of `getPageX` is wrong in `purescript-jquery`.

Comment: But it's not just `x` and `y` that have the problem. Even `lastPos.x` and `lastPos.y` end being an array instead of `Number` type, but they get their values from the `readSTRef` function. Also worth mentioning, I have another fuction in my program that also uses `readSTRef` but over there the value is assigned normally so I'm really confused as to why this is happening only inside `moveHandler`

Comment: [`getPageX`](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-jquery/blob/master/src/Control/Monad/Eff/JQuery.js#L303) returns jQuery instance instead of a Number

Comment: Is there something I can do to fix that?

Comment: @GeorgeV.M. A pull request fixing the issue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Phill Freeman and Yury Tarabanko in the comments, it turned out that `getPageX/Y` in `purescript-jquery` was returning the wrong type. It's been corrected now and after updating the package, the program executes as is and `newAngle` has the correct value.

Although an incorrect return type for `getPageX/Y` explains why `x` and `y` were incorrect, I was still confused about why `lastPos.x` and `lastPos.y` were also incorrect types even though they were assigned by `readSTRef`. It's only now that I realized my silly brain didn't think it through. `lastPos` stores the last mouse position and that position is *also* obtained from `getPageX/Y`. So both the weird types were caused by the same error.